# How to call two then's from a single Promise?

Tags: typescript, async-await

I use TypeScript and given is the following code:

```
fooOpen("xyz").then((r) => {
    return r.getBar();
}).then((bar) => {
   console.log(bar);
});

fooOpen("xyz").then((r) => {
    return r.getBas();
}).then((bas) => {
   console.log(bas);
});
```

Instead of executing `fooOpen('xyz')` **twice**, is there a way how to trigger `getBar` and `getBas` from a **single** call of `fooOpen('xyz')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with returning both your desired calls in an array like `[r.getBar(), r.getBas()];`.

**Edit** As per your comment `getBar` & `getBas` are `promises` then you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as `return Promise.all([r.getBar(), r.getBas()]);`

And inside `then` use [destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as `then(([bar, bas]) => {...}`.

Check complete code below.

```
fooOpen("xyz").then((r) => {
  return Promise.all([r.getBar(), r.getBas()]);
}).then(([bar, bas]) => {
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(bas);
});
```

Check output in below sample. Added `foo` and `fooOpen` for testing.

```js
class foo {
  getBar() {
    return Promise.resolve("bar");
  }
  getBas() {
    return Promise.resolve("bas");
  }
}

function fooOpen(a) {
  return new Promise(r => r(new foo()));
}

fooOpen("xyz").then((r) => {
  return Promise.all([r.getBar(), r.getBas()]);
}).then(([bar, bas]) => {
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(bas);
});
```

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work. `bar`, and `bas` becomes a Promise object themselves

Comment: I know it's just example code but please replace `new Promise(r => r(...))` with `Promise.resolve(...)`

Comment: Perfect, and thank you! That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

try using await

```
//pseudo code...
async combineResultsFunction():Promise<[]> {

const foo = await fooOpen("xyz");

const bar = await foo.getBar();
const bas = await foo.getBas();

return Promise.resolve([bas, bar]);

}
```

or combine with Promise.all()

```
//pseudo code...
async combineResultsFunction(): ... {
 const foo = await fooOpen("xyz");
 return Promise.all(foo.getBar(), foo.getBas())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately await is not a solution because it blocks the execution chain

Comment: execution is only blocked within the surrounding async function

Comment: As you are using `const bar = await foo.getBar();` it will be `object` not `Promise`. So `return [bas, bar];` will not return `Promise<[]>`.  You can omit `await` and use `const bar = foo.getBar();` to return `bas` as `Promise`.

Comment: `execution is only blocked within the surrounding async function` correct, that's why I can't use this